# assembly compile target in termux + prooted ubuntu in galaxy android

Tags: ubuntu, assembly, termux, samsung-galaxy

Hi assembly programmers,

I am a newbie using Galaxy Handphone S23 and want to compile hello-world assembly code
in termux-prooted-ubuntu environment. I checked to find CPU architecture is armv8-a.

---[hello.c]---
#include <stdio.h>

```
int main(char \*\*argv)
{
printf("Abc\\n");
return(0);
}
```

---[commands]---

```
gcc hello.c -S
as hello.s -o hello.o
ld hello.o -o hello
```

---[output]---

```
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol \_start; defaulting to 00000000004000b0
ld: hello.o: in function main': hello.c:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to puts
```

---[Question]---
Question is "what is right way to compile hello world assembly code ?"

Thank you.

I tried other options using :

```
nasm with different format and architecture
command is :
```

```
$ nasm -f $format hello.s -o hello.o
$ ld   -m $architecture hello.o -o hello
```

but no combination is working.

---[Architecture]---

```
aarch63linux
aarch64linux
aarch64elf
aarch64elf32
aarch64elf32b
aarch64elfb
armelf
armelfb
aarch64linuxb
aarch64linux32
aarch64linux32b
armelfb_linux_eabi
armelf_linux_eabi
```

---[format]---

```
bin
ith
srec
aout
aoutb
coff
elf32
elf64
elfx32
as86
obj
win32
win64
ieee
macho32
macho64
dbg
elf
macho
```

Comment: Link with the C compiler instead of with ld.

Comment: Thank fuz. The main reason for doing this is that I am trying to learn assembly by writing assembly code and compile it. If I can use C compiler for link, that would be fine. It would be appreicated if you can give me the command line statement.

Comment: Try `gcc -o hello hello.o`.

Comment: in my case, starting point must be assembly code :   soemthing like   "gcc   -XXX  hello.s -o hello"

Comment: As your assembler is nasm , you'll need to assemble with nasm and then link the resulting object with gcc.

Comment: nasm is for x86 not arm, you should use emulator like qmenu, try this solution: https://github.com/termux/termux-app/discussions/3173